# Two classes work with one ( C++)

Tags: c++

I have 3 classes: Scanner,Table,Reader. Scanner adds information to Table, and Reader reads from table. So, where should i declare Table variable? I did in .h, but there was the mistake of double including.

Comment: Please provide some code. Double inclusion can be solved by using include guards: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: You might *declare* the variable in a .h file (as `extern`), but it should be *defined* in a .cpp file.

Comment: sounds like you'll have to use forward declarations...

Comment: and include a #pragma once or #ifndef..

Comment: #ifndef - doesn't help

Comment: without code tough to diagnose, but i suspect @PaulR has the correct fix. header guards not the issue here

Comment: We could use some code, post your headers/cpp without implementations, just declarations, as the answers have shown.  Usually double inclusion can be fixed with include guards, and this is enough.  Certain circumstances require forward declarations.  Without code we can't be sure.

Comment: If you want to be able to have more then one instance of the Scanner-Table-Reader chain, you would store a pointer to the working table in `Scanner` and `Reader` rather then making a global variable. If you are sure, you will have only one instance, use the Paul's advice.

Answer (score 1):

A "mistake of double including" suggests to me that a single file was being included more than once in a single translation unit.  For example, suppose you have:

### table.h

```
#include "reader.h"

class Table
{
  Reader* mReader;
};
```

### reader.h

```
#include "table.h"
class Reader
{
};
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "table.h"
#include "reader.h"

int main()
{
  Table table;
}
```

When `main.cpp` is compiled, `table.h` will include 'reader.h', which will include `table.h`, etc ad infinitum.

There are at least two ways to solve this problem.

The first way, probably preferred in most circumstances, is to forward-declare your classes in cases where you don't need a full definition yet.  For example, `Table` has a pointer to `Reader`, and doesn't need a full definition:

### new-table.h

```
class Reader;
class Table
{
  Reader* mReader;
};
```

Judicious use of forward-declarations help to speed up compiles and, perhaps more importantly, reduce cyclic dependancies.

The second way is to use include guards:

### new-table.h

```
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H

#include "reader.h"

class Table
{
  Reader* mReader;
};
```

It is probably not a bad idea to use include-guards in all header files, whether you use forward-declarations or not, but I would suggest using forward-declarations whenever possible.

Answer (score -1):

May be like this:

```
// Scanner.h
#ifndef _Scanner_h_  // guard: ensure only one definition
#define _Scanner_h_

#include "Table.h"

class Scanner
{
    ....
    void add(Table & table);   // implemented in Scanner.cpp
};

#endif

// Reader.h
#ifndef _Reader_h_
#define _Reader_h_

#include "Table.h"

class Reader
{
    ...
    void read(const Table & table);  // implemented in Reader.cpp
};

#endif

// Table.h
#ifndef _Table_h_
#define _Table_h_

class Table
{
    ...
};

#endif
```

In main:

```
#include "Table.h"
#include "Scanner.h"
#include "Reader.h"

....
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    Table table;
    Scanner scanner;
    Reader reader

    scanner.add(table);
    ....
    reader.read(table);
    ....
}
```

Comment: you can remove header dependency using foward declare..always better..

Comment: @Dory Zidon: Yes, I agree, is only for aclaration purposes.

Comment: why are these answers downvoted?

Comment: Unfortunately, the user of my class should know nothing about table

Comment: Users of your class do not need to know anything about table. you can make it all private..

Comment: @DoryZidon relax he didnt downvote he doesnt have enough rep

Comment: You need include guards, this answer will have the same problem the poster is complaining about.  You will define table several times.  Once in each reader and scanner, and then again in main.  The same issue the poster is complaining about.

Comment: 1) It is lexical analyzer of Pascal-like language
2) i dont downvote

Comment: see my edit..I added the #pragma once / #ifndef...

Comment: ld: duplicate symbol _TID in /var/... and /var/... for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Is this an output related to your issue or what?  I'm unclear as to what this is.  If this is output, this is a linker error not a compilation error... very different.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you have a problem with multiple definition.
Use at the top of each header and include each C++ class in a header and footer.

```
#pragma once
class Name {}
//or
#ifndef __CLASS_NAME_H__
#define __CLASS_NAME_H__
class Name { }
#endif
```

i.e.

```
//Scanner.h
#pragma once //<---------- must use it so you do not have double include..
class Table; //forward decalre reduced dependendcy and no need to include h.
class Scanner {
    int ReadIntoTable(Table* pInTable);
}
```

---

```
//Scanner.cpp
// has method bodies that uses Table like   
#include "Table.h"
int Scanner::ReadIntoTable(Table* pInTable)
{
   pInTable->putData(123);
   return void.
}
```

---

```
//Table.h
#pragma once //<-------- use so you do not have double include.
class Table {
   getData();
   putData(int Data);
}
```

---

```
//Table.cpp 
// impelenation for table
```

Comment: why vote down? can someone explain ?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't downvote it, but I also wouldn't upvote it.  Lack of include guards in the .h file.  But my guess would be someone doesn't like/understand forward declarations.

Comment: I was editing my answer, and I saw your comment after

Comment: and forward declare is very useful at reducing header dependency, I spend hours on projects with complex header depenencies people created..